# how to format specify a const char * in C?

Tags: c, pointers, format-specifiers

I have this loop:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
```

but `word` here is a `const char *` not `char *`
so how should I change `%s`?

Comment: You're not going to change what a `const` pointer points to, no?

Comment: @iBug no, I just want to specify 'word' here.

Answer (score 5):

Since the `scanf` series is meant for reading input, it's expected that the provided pointer points to something writable. A `const char *` pointer cannot be used to modify what it points to (even if the target is actually writable), so in no way it should appear in a `scanf` to receive read data.

You should also note that `word` must point to some valid writable memory before being used in a call to `scanf`, or it will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: You might also mention that `word` as a `char *` pointer should point to an actual array before passing it to `scanf()` and that `%s` is unsafe as the maximum number of characters to store to the array is unknown.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean by “A `const char *` pointer cannot be used to modify what it points to (even if the target is actually writable)…” While the pointer cannot be used directly to modify the object, if the pointed-to object was not defined with `const` (so the `const` was added to the pointer later; it is not original to the object), then the C standard permits converting the `const char *` to `char *` and using that to modify the object.